# Вживання синонімів іноземний, іншомовний?

Tags: вживання-слів

Згідно з цим сайтом [http://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=Іноземні&t=0](http://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D0%86%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%96&t=0) та багатьма іншими офіційними сайтами, слова "іноземний" та "іншомовний" вважаються словами синонімами, а ось вживання їх з іменниками неоднозначне. Можна сказати "іноземна делегація" та "іншомовний текст", а навпаки вже буде не дуже коректно... Як правильно вживати такі синоніми?

Answer (score 3):

Згідно із [Словником синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)  слова "іноземний" та "іншомовний" дійсно є синонімами.

Приклади правильного вживання даних синонімів можемо побачити в [Літературне слововживання](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53382/30990.html):

> **Іноземний.** Який належить іншій країні, державі, чужому
>   краєві:*іноземний матрос, іноземні загарбники, інститут іноземних мов*
>   (але міністерство закордонних справ).
>
> **Іншомовний.** Про певні мовні(переважно лексичні) елементи – слова,
>   терміни, назви тощо: *словник іншомовних слів, іншомовні запозичення,
>   іншомовне видання.*

Також на сайті [Уроки державної мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/142.htm) зазначено:

> **Іноземний** — той, що належить іншій країні, чужому краєві: *іноземний матрос, іноземні загарбники, інститут іноземних мов* (але Міністерство закордонних справ).
>
> **Іншомовний** уживають тоді, коли йдеться не про мову в цілому, а про певні її елементи (переважно лексичні) — слова, терміни тощо:
>   іншомовне видання, іншомовні запозичення, іншомовна назва.

Answer (score 1):

*Інозе́мний* (синоніми: *чужозе́мний* / *чужозе́мський* <sub>розм.</sub>, *чужосторо́нній* <sub>розм.</sub>, *чужи́нський* / *чужи́нницький* / *чужи́нний* / *чужине́цький* <sub>розм.</sub>) та *іншомо́вний* (синоніми: *іномо́вний* <sub>рідко</sub>, *чужомо́вний*) не мають майже нічого спільного.

- *[іноземний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=39243&page=1232)* — це той, що стосується інших земель/територій;
- *[іншомовний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=39480&page=1247)* — це той, що стосується інших мов.

Навіть стосовно населення України і україномовних людей: в Україні мешкають не лише україномовні, а україномовні мешкають не лише в Україні. Але оскільки все-таки населення України і україномовних людей значною пірою перетинаються, то появню краще на прикладі франкомовного француза на ім'я Франсуа у Франції:

- якщо він пише листа іноземному товаришу — то це він пише листа товарищу, що перебуває не у Франції — при цьому товарищ цілком може бути теж франкомовним, як і сам Франсуа (наприклад, емігрантом або ж походити з будь-якої з країн, де теж пощирена французька: Бельгія, Швейцарія, Канада тощо);
- якщо він пише листа іншомовному товаришу — то він пише листа товарищу, що розмовляє не французькою — при цьому товарищ цілком може бути теж у Франції, як і сам Франсуа (наприклад, імігрантом чи гостем).

Іноземна книжка — це книжка, що видається і купується здебільшого за кордоном; іношомовна книжка — це книжка на іншій мові. Слово *[закордо́нний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=29856&page=982)* (синоніми: *зарубі́жний* / *заграни́чний* <sub>розм.</sub> (*замо́рський* <sub>застаріле, розм.</sub>)) й те ближче до слова *іноземний* (хоч це також не те саме), ніж *іншомовний*.

Єдиний контекст, де значення цих слів схожі — це мови і їхні елементи. Справа в тому, що про інші мови окрім української ми традиційно кажемо *іноземні*; ми не кажемо *іншомовні* мови, бо це тавтологія; не завжди підходить навіть словосполучення *інші* мови (бо слово *інший* занадто неконкретне, його зазвичай не застосовують без уточнення, в порівнянні до чого саме інші) або *чужі* мови (бо *чужий* має специфічніше забарвлення). Хоч це формально не зовсім логічно, адже українська для нас формально частково іноземна (частина українців живе за кордоном), а російська, їдиш, румунська тощо — формально частково неіноземні (частина населення України надають перевагу цим мовам) — але так склалося, причому не лише щодо української — наприклад, перекладаючи мемуари Франсуа, ми називатимемо вже інші мови, окрім французької, іноземними. Але штука в тому, що, як правильно сказано в [іншій відповіді](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3335), навіть у цьому контексті ці слова не взаємозамінні, бо ми застосовуємо *іноземний* у місцях, в яких за логікою мало б бути *іншомовний*, лише до самих мов, але зазвичай не до їхніх частин/елементів/аспектів (де на своє законне місце повертається логічно очікуване слово *іншомовний*: *іншомовні дієслова*, *ішномовні правила* тощо).

Тобто я б особисто не називав *іноземний* і *ішномовний* навіть частковими синонімами, адже спільне значення в них з'являється лише при їхньому застосуванні до різних іменників (слово *іноземний* реально відіграє слова *іншомовний* лише в тому випадку, коли саме слово *іншомовний* просто незастосовне: *іноземна мова* — в інших випадках значення слів нетотожні) — але упорядники словників вирішили інакше.